# Vue router Guard exclude to path with token

Tags: vue.js

I have implemented verification email in my app. After signup the user gets an url to verify email such as:

```
http://localhost:8080/verify_email/xdGCmMGz6LrBv0s_97gDvQ
```

I have a Router Guard in place with this condition:

```
else if (store.state.signedIn && !store.state.currentUser.email_confirmed && to.path !== '/warning_verify_email' && to.path !== '/verify_email/:token') next('/warning_verify_email')
```

route /warning_verify_email is a component the just gives a warning to check email and verify before proceeding.

The problem I am having is:

```
to.path !== '/verify_email/:token'
```

which should not make

```
http://localhost:8080/verify_email/xdGCmMGz6LrBv0s_97gDvQ
```

redirect to

```
/warning_verify_email
```

But it does.

In routes, `path: '/verify_email/:token'` works. So I was assuming it would have worked in the guard too. But it doesn't.

How can I fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is probably your condition.  `to.path` is the actual route not the definition, so in your example `to.path` will be `'/verify_email/xdGCmMGz6LrBv0s_97gDvQ'`.  You need to check `to.matched` instead:

```
const isVerifyRoute = to.matched.some(route => route.path === '/verify_email/:token');
```